# convert String to JSONArray using java

Tags: java, json

I need to convert String to JSONArray

The string size may vary from small Kbs (10kb) to GBs (1 or 2 GB).

My problem is explained in detail below :

I have saved the file as below

> ```
>     {
>         "data1": false,
>         "data2": “content,
>         "data3": false,
>         "data4": false,
>         "data5": "datavalue",
>         "createdTime": "2016-06-16 10:12:57.287Z",
>         "dataid": "12315005",
>         "data6": "out"
>     },
>     {
>         "data1": false,
>         "data2": “cccdeevevev”,
>         "data3": false,
>         "data4": false,
>         "data5": "datavalue",
>         "createdTime": "2016-06-02 17:48:13.000Z",
>         "dataid": "12311276",
>         "data6": "in"
>     },
>     {
>         "data1": false,
>         "data2": “dfsfergtrhtryjrutjbnhj”,
>         "data3": false,
>         "data4": false,
>         "data5": "datavalue",
>         "createdTime": "2016-06-02 17:48:13.000Z",
>         "dataid": "12312272",
>         "data6": "in"
>     },
>     {
>         "data1": false,
>         "data2": "dfsfergtrhtryjrutjbnhjwdwefwevqeqwre”,
>         "data3": false,
>         "data4": false,
>         "data5": "datavalue",
>         "createdTime": "2016-06-02 16:59:27.000Z",
>         "dataid": "12312336",
>         "data6": "in"
>     },
>     {
>         "data1": false,
>         "data2": "Cccccccl",
>
>         "data3": false,
>         "data4": false,
>         "data5": "datavalue",
>         "createdTime": "2016-06-02 16:59:27.000Z",
>         "dataid": "12311340",
>         "data6": "in"
>     },
>     {
>         "data1": false,
>         "data2": "Check asqdwqd”,
>         "data3": false,
>         "data4": false,
>         "data5": "datavalue",
>         "createdTime": "2016-06-02 16:56:46.000Z",
>         "dataid": "12312340",
>         "data6": "in"
>     },
>     {
>         "data1": false,
>         "data2": "Check wdwfdwfqfcw”,
>         "data3": false,
>         "data4": false,
>         "data5": "datavalue",
>         "createdTime": "2016-06-02 16:56:46.000Z",
>         "dataid": "12311344",
>         "data6": "in"
>     },
>     {
>         "data1": true,
>         "data2": "text",
>         "data3": false,
>         "data4": false,
>         "data5": "datavalue",
>         "createdTime": "2016-06-01 20:01:51.000Z",
>         "dataid": "12311099",
>         "data6": "in"
>     },
> ```
>
> What i am doing currently is :

I am reading the above file and converting it into string. Before converting string to JSONarray , I replaced last comma with "" and appended [ and ] at the first and last respectively. Then using below i am converting string to JSON Array as :

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(String);
```

I'm using the org.json.JSONArray.

I have saved file as above, because I'll append the additional similar JSON Object to the file once I got info related it. The file will grow in size subsequently.

What am I doing now affects the performance of the server once file size grows.

Also Unable to do random access from the JSONArray. I need to traverse through the array to get data of one data id.(Sequential access only possible)

Please provide solution for this to get random access of data and relatively fast performance.

Comment: You want a library that parses JSON for you. GSON is one of them.

Comment: GB of json, seriously? You should use some DBMS

Comment: I'm storing String Content in Big data type (HDFS) of storage. While retrieving I have to parse the content as JSON in order to get value for the keys.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos GSON will parse the string. Is the random access possible via GSON?

Comment: It's still going to be all in-memory, so you might want to be selective in what you pull from HDFS, but yes, you can do random access. However, you are using HDFS wrong; just put the data into the underlying Hadoop instance, *as it's already structured*, and do a bloody query to get exactly the data you need.

Comment: @RC You mean parse the json and store in DBMS row by row. Seriously ? Should go for non-relational right ?

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan no I mean change the thing that generates the json to make it write into some DB

Comment: @RC. Content may be big and also it's not going to be modified at any time. Instead of using relational Database, I'm preferring to go for no-sql database. Is it fine?

Comment: Anything that provide indexing and a query system will be fine IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you would be able to `stream` data in GB with a `client` which is a mobile device, you have to refine this to send data as required.

Instead of reading this as a file you should have some API which will mediate between your server data (`Database`) and client (`Mobile`).

Depending on what information you want, You can tell that to the API something like this

```
www.example.com/api/readRecords ? fromID=20 & toID=25
```

I have included the space that it would be easy to read. In this manner you can retrieve data from ID `20` to `25`, something which would look like this, and off course use `GSON`

```
{
  data: [
    {
      "data1": false,
      "data2": “content,
      "data3": false,
      "data4": false,
      "data5": "datavalue",
      "createdTime": "2016-06-16 10:12:57.287Z",
      "dataid": "12315005",
      "data6": "out"
    },
    {
      "data1": false,
      "data2": “cccdeevevev”,
      "data3": false,
      "data4": false,
      "data5": "datavalue",
      "createdTime": "2016-06-02 17:48:13.000Z",
      "dataid": "12311276",
      "data6": "in"
    },
    {
      "data1": false,
      "data2": “dfsfergtrhtryjrutjbnhj”,
      "data3": false,
      "data4": false,
      "data5": "datavalue",
      "createdTime": "2016-06-02 17:48:13.000Z",
      "dataid": "12312272",
      "data6": "in"
    }
  ],
  metaData: {
    fromID: 20,
    toID: 22
  }
}
```

And do attach some `MetaData` to the response that it would be easier for client(`Mobile`) to know what you are sending

Comment: I have read in some site that Jackson is so fast than GSON.Is it true? Also Using GSON Streaming, How to append the [ bracket in the content of the file. Or else I may use some other form of Big data like Cassandra, Hbase to store data and retrieve it.

Comment: the question is not who is fast but you should concentrate on breaking the data into parts so it can be sent over the network without any load on either server or client

Answer (score -1):

You should Use some Non relational Databases like `Mongo DB`. JSON is the basic format in Mongo as well. Store your json array there and Query as per requirement.

[Mongo DB](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community)

Comment: Downvoter please comment the reason. So that I can improve the answer